# Set ravendb silverlight client timeout

Tags: silverlight, timeout, client, ravendb

I'm using ravendb silverlight client.
Is there a way to setup a timeout for erver requests?
Thanks,
Alex

Comment: RavenDb uses `HttpWebRequest` internally which does not provide API in silverlight for setting the TimeOut...

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
documentStore.JsonRequestFactory.CustomizeRequest = (sender, args) = ((HttpWebRequest)arg.Request).Timeout = 1000;
```